# How does CID help in combat when called to be a follower / homie?

Tags: saints-row-iv

The Upgrades - Gang Abilities menu description for the 'HOMIE - C.I.D.' gang ability states that:

> *C.I.D. can be called into the simulation using your HUB "PHONE" menu.
>   The A.I. will help the saints in combat.*

However, it seems that aside from having hilarious dialogue with some of the other homies and following me around, it seems that C.I.D. doesn't do anything to help in combat.

Screenshot of C.I.D. just looking at me while I'm being shot at by aliens:

[image]

I've [searched](https://www.google.com/search?q=c.i.d.+saints+row+iv+~combat) and found the following posts asking the same thing but they currently have no replies:

- [Does the C.I.D. help in battle? | saintsrow.com](http://saintsrow.com/community/go/thread/view/144675/30062407/Does_the_C.I.D._help_in_battle)
- [What does CID do in battle? | steamcommunity.com](http://steamcommunity.com/app/206420/discussions/0/846961716500255152/)

**What helpful things does CID do when called to be a follower / homie?**

Comment: Making you laugh is debatably helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [CID entry](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/CID#Homie) on the Saints Row 4 wiki,

> As a Homie, CID does nothing to help The Protagonist in any way, he only speaks and has homie conversations, he does not fight in battle but follows the boss around. He is seen using some sort of weapon in cutscenes only.

So CID does not help in combat, and will only follow you around and have hilarious dialogue with your other homies.